# Dropdown displays list elements next to each other instead of below each other

Tags: html, css

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background: #343434;
  height: 20 px;
}

ul li a.home {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 0px;
  padding: 20px 100px;
  margin: 0px 30px;
}

ul li a.home:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  transition: .5s;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 80px;
}

.main ul {
  display: none;
}

ul li a {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 100px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #A179C9;
  color: black;
  transition: .7s;
}

.main li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main">
  <li><a class="home" href="index.html">blank</a></li>
  <li><a href="listen.html">listen</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a id="spotify" href="https://open.spotify.com/">spotify</a></li>
      <li><a id="apple" href="https://open.spotify.com/">apple music</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="gallery.html">gallery</a></li>
  <li><a href="download.html">download</a></li>
  <li><a href="store.html">store</a></li>

</ul>
```

The "spotify" and "apple music" block elements display in one line next to each other as opposed to below each other.

I also use bootstrap on the page. Not sure if it's got anything to do with the issue because when I remove the script it still works the same.

Sorry if my code is hard to see through.

Answer (score 0):

It's the `inline-block` on `ul li` in your CSS. `inline-block` won't break the line. See [MDN Inline Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements).

Answer (score 0):

in css I marked my edits.

was it necessary?

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background: #343434;
  height: 20 px;
}

ul li a.home {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 0px;
  padding: 20px 100px;
  margin: 0px 30px;
}

ul li a.home:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  transition: .5s;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 80px;
}

.main ul {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column; /*add this it*/
  position: absolute; /*add this it*/
}

ul li a {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 100px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #A179C9;
  color: black;
  transition: .7s;
}

.main li:hover>ul {
  display: flex; /*add this it*/
  position: absolute; /*add this it*/
}
```

```html
<ul class="main">
  <li><a class="home" href="index.html">blank</a></li>
  <li><a href="listen.html">listen</a>
    <ul class="sub_main">
      <li><a id="spotify" href="https://open.spotify.com/">spotify</a></li>
      <li><a id="apple" href="https://open.spotify.com/">apple music</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="gallery.html">gallery</a></li>
  <li><a href="download.html">download</a></li>
  <li><a href="store.html">store</a></li>

</ul>
```